# Using JSTL with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I know this is not the first question regarding this but I failed to find an answer that would resolve my issue.

In my project I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 and run it on IBM WebSphere AS 7.

I have created a very simple page to demonstrate the issue and hope that SO community will help me figure out :)

So, here's the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:panel>
            <c:if test="#{true}">
                <h:outputText value="WORKS!!!" />
            </c:if> 
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This page produces the following HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/APP/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bluesky" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/APP/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/APP/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/APP/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="j_idt6" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div id="j_idt6_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
                WORKS!!!
            </div>
        </div>
        <script id="j_idt6_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('Panel','widget_j_idt6',{id:'j_idt6'});</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have a slightly modified page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:panel>
            <c:if test="#{bean != null}">
                <h:outputText value="WORKS!!!" />
            </c:if> 
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Which produces the following HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/APP/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bluesky" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="j_idt6" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div id="j_idt6_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
                WORKS!!!
            </div>
        </div>
        <script id="j_idt6_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('Panel','widget_j_idt6',{id:'j_idt6'});</script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The two pages should have been rendered **IDENTICALLY**, but they are different.
The difference is that the latter page is missing `primefaces.css` and `jQuery` related libraries, but they are **required** to be loaded. And more complicated pages fail due to this. But this happens only when I access page for the first time. If I click browser refresh buttons, everything is being generated the right way.

I don't really understand why this happens. As per my understanding `JSTL` tags are being processed before `JSF`. We can think of it like an ordinary `JSP` page, but with non-`HTML` layout which later fed to `JSF` handler. So this should not affect which resources are to be loaded.

I know that I can force output links using `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` but I expect it to work out of the box.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Everything says "WORKS!!!"

Comment: The problem is that the second example didn't include PrimeFaces CSS and `jQuery` libraries. But it should have included them.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove JSTL. and try to do it with JSF. for this type of Checking you can use preRenderView.

the problem is JSTL Component and JSF component rendering behavior is Different. You can read

BALUC's blog for that. now you can use

```
<f:event listener="#{user.isAdmin}" type="preRenderView" />

public void isAdmin(ComponentSystemEvent event){

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (!"admin".equals(fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("role"))){

        ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav 
           = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) 
            fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

        nav.performNavigation("access-denied");
    }       
  }
```

for more information you can check following link.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. And the problem doesn't seem to be in the fact that I use JSTL, else both examples would evaluate to the same result. Or worse, JSTL tags would appear in resulting HTMLs. Thanks for you help anyway.